# Solr 1.4 - Spatial search, missing last query object

Tags: solr, spatial

Recently i've upgraded my Solr from 1.3 to 1.4 and I'm happy for this. Now I faced a strange problem and I would like to see if you have the same problem or I'm missing something.

I've run a query and put in this a PLACE with latitude and longitude, thus i could retrieve this with a spatial search (which it already works). If I run a query via ID, I retrieve this PLACE with the schema info, latitude and longitude are correct. When I run a spatial query (with latitude and longitude of the PLACE), in the xml result I don't see my place.

XML's PLACE:

```xml
<add>
<doc>
    <field name="id">PLC||77173</field>
    <field name="document_type">PLACE</field>
    <field name="document_type_content"><![CDATA[POI]]></field>
    <field name="latitude">45.07475</field>
    <field name="longitude">7.680215</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

Ok, if I'm going to query solr with "id:PLC||77173" (primary key), here the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<response> 

<lst name="responseHeader"> 
 <int name="status">0</int> 
 <int name="QTime">139</int> 
 <lst name="params"> 
  <str name="indent">on</str> 
  <str name="start">0</str> 
  <str name="q">id:PLC||77173
</str> 
  <str name="rows">10</str> 
  <str name="version">2.2</str> 
 </lst> 
</lst> 
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0"> 
 <doc> 
  <str name="document_type">PLACE</str> 
  <str name="document_type_content">POI</str> 
  <str name="id">PLC||77173</str> 
  <double name="latitude">45.07475</double> 
  <double name="longitude">7.680215</double> 
 </doc> 
</result> 
</response>
```

Now, I'm going to type the following query

> qt=geo&lat=45.07475&long=7.680215&q=(document_type:PLACE)&radius=10&unit=km&wt=json

And in my json/xml (just erase json from the query) there's no trace of my PLACE (PLC||77173). I prefere don't paste the xml response, is too big.

Comment: please post some examples to illustrate your issue.

Comment: Resolved: it seems that solr takes some time before refresh his spatial search, in fact now i can see the PLACE. Thanks anyway :)